# annotate a formula (with bqoute or substitute) in R (ggplot) gives Error

Tags: r, ggplot2, formula, annotate

I want to add a formula with variables in it as a annotation onto my ggplot.

```
regline1 <- 0.00
slope1 <- 1.00
dat <- as.data.frame(c(0,1))
dat[2] <- c(0,1)
names(dat) <- c("foo","bar")

p <-
ggplot(dat, aes(foo, bar)) + coord_fixed(ratio = 1) + geom_point()  + 
geom_abline(slope = slope1, intercept = intercept1, linetype = "dashed") +
labs(x =  substitute(y[H1]==i+s%*%x,list(i=format(intercept1, digits = 1), s= format(slope1, digits = 1))))
```

As you can see it is no problem for ggplot to evaluate the formula for labs(x =...), but if you try to add an annotation:

```
p +   annotate("text",x=0.75, y = 0.25, label = substitute(y[H1]==i+s%*%x,list(i=format(intercept1, digits = 1), s= format(slope1, digits = 1))))
```

it will give you an Error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): label
```

I can parse a paste-call in annotate() like this:

```
p <- annotate("text",x= 0.75, y =0.25, label = "paste(y[H1]== intercept1+ slope1 %.%x)", parse = TRUE)
```

However, this does not write the variable values, since its in quotation marks. The substitute()-expression in quotation marks will not be parsed at all.

So how can I do this?

Any help is appreciated,
thanks in advance
Julius

Comment: annotate("text",x= 0.75, y =0.25, label = "bquote(y[H2]==.(intercept2)+.(slope2)%.%x)", parse = TRUE) does not get parsed as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [annotate() function does not support expressions](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1548). you need to pass in a string and set `parse=T`.

If you first build your expression

```
myexpr <- substitute( y[H1]==i+s%*%x, list(
    i = format(intercept1, digits = 1), 
    s= format(slope1, digits = 1))
)
```

You can `deparse()` it and have `annotate()` re-parse it for you

```
ggplot(dat, aes(foo, bar)) + 
    geom_point()  + 
    geom_abline(slope = slope1, intercept = intercept1, linetype = "dashed") +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 1) + 
    labs(x = myexpr) + 
    annotate("text",x=0.75, y = 0.25, label = deparse(myexpr), parse=TRUE)
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: I don't. I just tried with your example above in a fresh R session (after setting `intercept1<-0`). Tested with `R 3.3.1` and `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: Yes, you are right. In an empty session it works for me as well, but with my real data the error consists... 'myexpr' works fine in lab(x=...) but not as annotate. I don't get it

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's really hard to guess what might be going on.

Comment: It is a problem of how i get slope1 and intercept1 from my regession1. with:     slope1 <- regline1$coefficients[2]; intercept1 <- regline1$coefficients[1] I get named numbers, which can not be parsed (?). So I have to unname them with as.numeric. This did the trick. Thanks for the fast answer!