# Insertion of leq symbol in substitute, Mathematical Annotation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, substitution, mathematical-expressions

I have the following graph:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mm<-70
sdm<-12
weight_lim<-c(30, 110)
xrange<-55
ggplot(data = data.frame(weight = weight_lim), aes(weight)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = mm, sd = sdm),color=1) +
  ylab("f(weight)") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(weight_lim[1],weight_lim[2], by=5)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mm,sd=sdm),
                xlim = c(weight_lim[1],xrange[1]),
                geom = "area",fill="red",alpha=0.5)+
  annotate("text", x = 40, y = .02, 
           label = substitute(paste("P(X < ",v," ) = ",s),list(v=format(xrange, nsmall = 1),s=round(pnorm(xrange,mm,sdm),4))),
           size=3 , fontface="bold")+
  theme_bw()
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I would like to replace “<” by "less than or equal to" sign in

`substitute(paste("P(X < ",v," ) = ",s),list(v=format(xrange, nsmall = 1),s=round(dnorm(xrange,mm,sdm),4)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
vv = format(xrange, nsmall = 1)
ss = round(dnorm(xrange,mm,sdm),4)
```

Then either of these will work.

```
lab = bquote(P(X <= .(vv)) == .(ss)) 
# or
lab = substitute(P(X <= v) == s, list(v=vv, s=ss))

p + annotate("text", x = 40, y = .02, label = deparse(lab), parse=TRUE)
```

Noting from [annotate a formula (with bqoute or substitute) in R (ggplot) gives Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262808/annotate-a-formula-with-bqoute-or-substitute-in-r-ggplot-gives-error) that `annotate` doesn't take expressions., hence the `deparse/parse` stuff to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: ... and just noticed you probably want `pnorm`

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to insert a character is to use the `\u` escape sequence.  It's used just like any of the other escape sequences, where the Unicode character code follows `\u`.  You can see the example here:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  annotate('text', x=300, y=29, label='Unicode 2264: \u2264') +
  annotate('text', x=300, y=26, label='Unicode 2265: \u2265')
```

[image]

As you can see, less than or equal to is Unicode 2264, so just use `\u2264` directly in your label.